# Oracle doesn't inherit number scale and precision for columns in a view consumed by Kafka Connect

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, oracle19c

I want to force a column from my view to have an exact scale and precision. My current preset is as follows:

```
create or replace view v1
as
select cast(1 as number(1,0))   as some_val,
       'X'                      as join_val
from dual
/
create or replace view v2
as
select v1.some_val
from dual
left join v1 on dual.dummy = v1.join_val
/
```

In this example I expect `v2.some_val` column to be `NUMBER(1,0)`. But when querying dictionary I get just `NUMBER`:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jul 12 13:02:59 2021
Version 19.9.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Mon Jul 12 2021 12:59:02 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0

SQL> column data_precision format 99;
SQL> column data_scale format 99;
SQL> column table_name format a5;
SQL> column column_name format a10;
SQL> select d.data_precision, d.data_scale, d.table_name, d.column_name
  2  from dba_tab_cols d
  3  where d.owner = 'STAT_INT'
  4  and d.table_name in ('V1', 'V2');

DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE TABLE COLUMN_NAM
-------------- ---------- ----- ----------
             1          0 V1    SOME_VAL
                          V1    JOIN_VAL
                          V2    SOME_VAL

SQL>
```

I've changed join condition in `V2` view (replaced join predicate to always true one):

```
create or replace view stat_int.v2
as
select v1.some_val
from dual
left join v1 on 1=1
/
```

And output changed:

```
SQL> select d.data_precision, d.data_scale, d.table_name, d.column_name
  2  from dba_tab_cols d
  3  where d.owner = 'STAT_INT'
  4  and d.table_name in ('V1', 'V2');

DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE TABLE COLUMN_NAM
-------------- ---------- ----- ----------
             1          0 V1    SOME_VAL
                          V1    JOIN_VAL
             1          0 V2    SOME_VAL

SQL>
```

I don't get why Oracle decides not to inherit scale and precision from parent table column because even if left join doesn't work it will be still `NULL` values that can be of type `NUMBER(1,0)`.

Of course, when I cast `some_val` to `NUMBER(1,0)` in `V2` view it works fine but in my case I keep this logic inside of `V1` view and it is used by a great number of dependent views (`V2` is one of them) which I don't want to change in order to just cast to an needed type.

This scale/precision requirement comes from Kafka Connect which transforms plain value `0` or `1` to something like `OxdP6jOQnr/o+UfE4q0zr5p7lMvK0Fh9N+fohbLmyY9Nt9u5ZoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=` if an appropriate scale isn't set.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that `NULL` can not be casted as `number(1,0)`.

The problem is that the view can return two possible *data types*,

`number(1,0)` in case the join will return a value or

`null casted as number` in case the join fails.

So here apply the Conversion Rules documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-F29BC3C8-11FF-4712-97F3-C7F0487C0D09)

> When manipulating numeric values, Oracle usually adjusts precision and scale to allow for maximum capacity.

Which leads in end effect in loss of the precision and scale.

You may observe a similar effect in a `UNION ALL` query, which suffers the same loss.

```
create or replace view v2
as 
select v1.some_val from v1
union  all
select   null  from dual
```

So I'd extremely enjoy to be wrong here, but I assume, you'll have to step down to an inner join or additionaly cast the value in the final view.

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation! Seems like I gotta cast a value explicitly in the top-most view.